# Split Geometry / LineString by vertex and not on intersect

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis

I would like to cut the lines by vertex. It does not work as I wish because there are lines that cross. The current query that I split the lines by vertex and also as soon as the lines intersect.
I only want it to cut at vertices and not at line crossings.
Thank you
[image]
Here is the SQL

```
WITH gpx_line AS (
SELECT uuid, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(lag((pt).geom, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY uuid ORDER by uuid, (pt).path), (pt).geom)) AS wkb_geometry
  FROM (SELECT uuid, ST_DumpPoints(wkb_geometry) AS pt FROM public.points_gpx_to_line) as dumps
)
SELECT * FROM gpx_line WHERE wkb_geometry IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Really sorry, I found the error. By the way, the lines were already segmented at the intersections.
I cleaned the data and the sql is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data and the expected results it is hard to know for sure what you're trying to achieve, but I believe what you described can be done with [`ST_DumpSegments`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html):

> A set-returning function (SRF) that extracts the coordinates (vertices) of a geometry. It returns a set of geometry_dump rows, each containing a geometry (geom field) and an array of integers (path field).

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
   (ST_DumpSegments('LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 3,4 4)'::geometry)).geom);
      st_astext      
---------------------
 LINESTRING(1 1,2 2)
 LINESTRING(2 2,3 3)
 LINESTRING(3 3,4 4)
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Very interesting. It meets my need with clean data. thanks for the help